# How to display specific blocks for specific roles alone w.r.t domains and subdomains

Tags: 7, blocks

I want to display specific blocks for specific roles alone with respect to domains and sub-domains. I know i can give permission for roles in the block to be displayed.How do i differentiate anonymous users with respect to domain and sub-domains in the permission of roles. Help really appreciated.Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you,

In Drupal 7 you can use these modules

- [Domain Context](https://drupal.org/project/domaincontext) - It allows administrators to set specific settings for each of their domains that are using the same code base.
- [Domain Blocks](https://drupal.org/project/domain_blocks) - Enables domain specific visibility settings for blocks.
- And for specific roles for each block you can select the roles. Go to your specific BLOCK configuration and select the **ROLE** in **BLOCK VISIBILITY SETTINGS**

  [image]